# Compressor for spray gun and pneumatics tools

Tags: powertools, compressor, air-compressor, spray-paint

I have a general question that I can't find answers to : can I use a commercial compressor that will provide pressure for all the tools that I have in my wearhouse and use the same compressor for my spray gun (using appropriate filters and valves)? If so, is it a cost efficient way ? Or 2 different compressor would be better?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually as long as the compressor/tank is big/powerful enough should be okay.  Most have a valve to regulate the output air pressure.  If the spraying and warehouse is done at two different locations, then moving a big compressor would become a pain very fast.

Comment: Pressure is only part of equation, you also need volume. You need to know what volume and pressure is required for each tool. Then add up the requirements for each tool you will be operating concurrently. You then need to come up with enough compressor(s) to supply this amount plus a cushion (I like about 25%). You now know your minimum compressor capacity. Increasing the pressure tank size will cause it to cycle less frequently the compressor supplies the maximum steady state air available. If you pipe it you need a water trap at the compressor and all lines should travel uphill from there.

Comment: You are not likely to use tools continuously so the storage tank will make up some capacity. For example , I have painted a few cars with a compressor that was a little lower capacity than the spray gun required. But I sprayed a few passes , then stopped and moved  It gave the compressor plenty of time to rebuild pressure.

Comment: We don’t have enough information to answer. What will you be spray painting? How often will you be painting? Are you in the USA? The reason is that spray painting is complex and there are multiple kinds of sprayers. HVLP, LVLP, and siphoned high pressure nozzles that you are asking about. The latter siphoned systems aren’t really used anymore in a work setting and they are not recommended for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Every pneumatic sander, spray gun, etc will have a requirement for a certain cfm (air volume) rate at a given pressure.

If you buy a compressor big enough to support your greediest tool, then the normal ones like air nailers will be fine.

You will probably need to install pressure regulators in places to lower the psi for certain tools.

Comment: If it's _one person_ using the compressor, one tool at a time, you're certainly good to go with just one. If you've got a shop full of guys using air at any time they need it, there's a significant chance that you won't have a compressor with a big enough tank _and_ enough CFM to support _all_ the tools needed _at once_. In that case a 2nd compressor would be a great bonus, and this would be as good a time as any to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be yes you can use a standard industrial air compressor the same as any other compressor.

There may be an advantage to using an industrial compressor as many times there are special water separators not only the simple sintered Bronze/ separation bowl but many times a system that chills the air to pull the moisture out of the air and achieve a dew point well below the simple separation filters.

As long as your system has the capacity it will probably be cleaner and dryer air (at least if the facility is using the air in air logic or control valves).